# onCreateViewHolder always returning -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How come my onCreateViewHolder position is always -1? I just can't seem to figure out why

viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() is always -1

```
@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterAllComments.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int a) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_rv_allcomments_container, viewGroup, false);


    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);



    for(int i = 0; i<mDepth.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); i++) {
        View divider = LayoutInflater.from(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
               .inflate(R.layout.groupie_section_item_divider, viewHolder.viewHolderLayout, false);
        viewHolder.viewHolderLayout.addView(divider);

    }



    return viewHolder;
}
```

The error:

```
     ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
    at com.example.evan.foodforum2.AdapterAllComments.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterAllComments.java:72)
    at com.example.evan.foodforum2.AdapterAllComments.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterAllComments.java:18)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you’re programmatically adding a divider view to the ViewHolder when you can do that in the ViewHolder’s layout XML file? And why are you creating a new instance of `ViewHolder`? That should be done on the `viewGroup` itself.

Comment: @Edric yes it is based on a value from JSON

Comment: But I don’t see any conditional logic for checking if the item should have a divider.

Comment: mDepth is an arraylist. if the integer is 5 I inflate it 5 times. I need the position of the adapter so I can determine the index of the array

Comment: So what’s in the mDepth array?

Comment: The adding of the divider view should probably be done in `onBindViewHolder` instead, where you can access the adapter’s position with the `position` argument.

Comment: "As per docs it should be done in onCreateViewHolder. Inflating inside onBindViewHolder is very bad design. It will make your recyclerView laggy and clumsy." It works inside onBindViewHolder but I'm trying to move it to onCreateViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

> I just can't seem to figure out why viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() is always -1.

Well, actually is simple:

```
// You are creating a new instance of the `ViewHolder`
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

// and then immediately are calling
viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
```

But this `ViewHolder` is not attached to anything yet, eg.: `RecyclerView` is not using it, the adapter is not initialised, so you receive `-1` because the default value of the adapter position is `-1`.

If you want to have dividers between list items, then you should look into  [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html).

Comment: Should I inflate them in onBindViewHolder then? And they are multiple vertical dividers in a single list item.